# Copying the value in a cell based on other cells matching

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm sure this is a simple problem to solve but I am struggling so thought I would seek help.

Basically I have the following setup:

Team Names in Column A
Points scored in Column B

I want to then enter the Team Names in Column C and to then have a formula in Column D which checks the name I've added to Column C against the names in Column A and automatically shows the points scored from Column B.

So as an example -
Column A = "Man Utd"
Column B = "3"
I then type "Man Utd" into Column C and would want "3" (from Column B) to automatically appear in Column D.

I guess this is possible but I have tried various VLOOKUP, MATCH, IF (to name a few) formulae with no joy.
If anyone can assist it would be appreciated.

Edited Addition:

The spreadsheet I am devising is to help me with the scoring of a football (or soccer depending where you're from) forum game I run. The idea is that each player picks 10 football teams and they get a point for each goal scored. However, they also pick one team which they think will not score any goals. If their team doesn't score they get 3 points but if the team does score they lose a point for every goal the team scores.

For example - Example A) The player picks Man Utd to not score a goal but they score 3. This means that the player would score -3 points. Example B) The player picks Man Utd to not score a goal and they don't. This means that the player would score 3 points.

Is there a way to create a similar formula to what has been suggested below that, for this selection, would match the team in the list in Column A to what I have entered in Column C and if the score next to this team (in Column B) is "0" it allocates 3 points to the relevant cell in Column D but if the score in Column B is above 0 (eg 3), the result in the relevant cell of Column D reads as minus the value shown in Column B (eg -3).

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks again

Comment: next time share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Are you suggesting I post a new question relating to the additional request I edited into the original post here and post a copy of my sheet (although it would have to be a dumbed down version as it has some personal info on it) along with it? @player0

Comment: kinda. next time when you will have some other question consider adding a sample sheet with an example of the desired output and a brief explanation in the post/question. lots of ppl don't have time to read bulk texts and recreate whole spreadsheet example from pointers in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP( C2,A2:B,2,0),"pick a team")
```

[image]

You need to use `0` or `FALSE` if the teams are NOT sorted. You otherwise use `1` or `TRUE`.

If you want to return more than one teams you will also need the  `ARRAYFORMULA` function.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,A2:B,2,0)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks very much! I have another query relating to the same spreadsheet but I wasn't sure whether to start a new question or not. I've decided to add the additional question to the bottom of my original post above (apologies if this was the wrong thing to do) - if it is something you can help with as well it would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4ytE.png) what you mean? Total points of player one is +1 point for every goal of the teams picked + points from No score team (if 0 goals=+3 points, if more than 0=-1 point for every goal)

Comment: Yes, the logic of your formula works but I just needed to amend to suit my spreadsheet.I only wanted this aspect of the formula to work within the specific cell for each player which relates to the no score team so I have reduced your formula down to "=IF(-VLOOKUP( D13,$A$2:$B,2,0)=0,3,-VLOOKUP( D13,$A$2:$B,2,0))" and this has done the trick perfectly. Thanks once again for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could help. As mentioned, you should normally create a new question for this answer. I can then give you a "proper" answer. Not many people make it to the comments, which means you and I are probably the only people knowing the solution to your edited question. Also, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will make sure I follow those next time. If it helps in this case, I will happily load up a new question for the edited question if you want me to and are willing to copy your answer over to make it easier for anyone else searching for this solution? Just let me know!

Comment: If you want to create the question, I will come along later and answer it. I would like to add some more info so as to complete the answer.

Comment: I have opened the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955984/formula-to-create-multiple-possible-results

Comment: Great. You should not prevent viewers form making a copy of the sheet though.

Comment: I think I have amended that now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you were using the VLOOKUP function. The first parameter is the string we are going to find. The second parameter should represent a tabular section. In your case, it should cover A and B columns.

After finding the value in column C, it should display the corresponding value in the second column of our tabular section. ("second" column of our tabular section is indicated in our 3rd parameter of VLOOKUP function)

[image]