# Formula to create multiple possible results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The spreadsheet I am devising is to help me with the scoring of a football (or soccer depending where you're from) forum game I run. The idea is that each player picks 10 football teams and they get a point for each goal scored. However, they also pick one team which they think will not score any goals. If their team doesn't score they get 3 points but if the team does score they lose a point for every goal the team scores.

For example - Example A) The player picks Man Utd to not score a goal but they score 3. This means that the player would score -3 points. Example B) The player picks Man Utd to not score a goal and they don't. This means that the player would score 3 points.

Is there a way to create a formula for this specific selection to go into cells `F13` and `J13` which would match the team in the list in Column A to what I have entered in Column D and H and if the score next to this team (in Column B) is "0" it allocates 3 points to the cell `F13` and `J13` but if the score in Column B is above 0 (eg 3), the value in cell `F13` and `J13` reads as minus the value shown in Column B (eg -3).

Template spreadsheet can be found here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNOVUGPAJF-nR9XtQ1fc-lqm4fYHNBJgz7-rr6SzJaU/edit?usp=sharing (not sure if I have set it correctly to allow editing but if I have then feel free to edit away)

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following formula on your `F13` cell (and all the corresponding ones for the rest of the players)

```
=IF(-VLOOKUP( D13,$A$2:$B,2,0)=0,3,-VLOOKUP( D13,$A$2:$B,2,0))
```

[image]

You could probably use a single formula on your `F1` cell.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C1:C11=TRUE,C1:C11*E1:E11,1))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)